# Derivatives of partial, conditional expectations

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions

I'm struggling with a derivative. First start with
$$H(b) = \int_{0}^{b} x dF(x),$$
where $x$ is a lognormally distributed random variable, and $F(x)$ is the cdf, $b$ is a cutoff point.

Now I need the following derivative:
$$\frac{d}{db}\frac{H(b)}{F(b)},$$
where $F(b)$ is the cdf evaluated at the cutoff point $b$.
I believe one would call $H(b)$ a partial expectation, and the fraction is the conditional expectation.
I tried applying the Leibnitz rule to $H(b)$, giving me
$$\frac{d}{db}H(b)=bf(b),$$
where $f(b)$ is the pdf at point $b$.  Then I used the quotient rule for the fraction
$$\frac{d}{db}\frac{H(b)}{F(b)} = \frac{bf(b)}{F(b)}- \frac{f(b)H(b)}{F(b)^{2}}.$$

Is this correct, and can I simplify it more?

Comment: It is correct. I was playing around with it in Maple and it seems like $H(b)$ can be expressed as $E[X]\bigl(\Phi(\sigma^{-1}(-\log b - \mu)) - 1\bigr)$ for $X\sim \operatorname{LN}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\Phi$ being the CDF of a standard Gaussian, but I have no proof of that.